# Hyperlinks change the content of the object tag

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have created a navigation menu that I have been inserting into my pages using the "object" tag. Whenever I click a link on the navigation menu, it takes me to the correct page but it is inside the object tag. The rest of the page remains the same including the original address in the address bar. I cannot seem to find anyone else having the same issue as I am.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/body.css" />

<body>
<object id="navigation" type="text/html" data="/includes/inc.nav.php"></object>

<div id='page'>
    <div id='pageTitle'>Knowledge Base</div>
    <p>Here is the body</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

inc.nav.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/navbar.css" />

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Tickets</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/vision/tickets.php">BLAH</a></li>
        <li><a href="/vision/tickets.php">Haha</a></li>
        <li><a href="/vision/tickets.php">Woohoo</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Equipment</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/vision/trucks.php">Trucks</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="/vision/reports.php">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="/vision/users.php">User List</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/vision/knowledgebase.php">Knowledge Base</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm sure I am missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can, please post the code you're using to create the link on the navigation menu. Maybe you'll need to look into the tag `a` -> `target`.

Comment: It was the target tag! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Found information on the answer here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Links should look like this:

```
    <li><a target="_parent" href="/vision/tickets.php">BLAH</a></li>
```